# How do I use UriBuilder for relative Uri so that the output is exactly like the input but with the path changed?

Tags: c#, .net, string, url

I need a method that does a redirection on URLs. The input can be absolute or relative URLs like these:

```
Inp: test/something.js?v=1#a
Out: testcontent/something.js?v=1#a

Inp: /test/something.js?v=1#a
Out: /testcontent/something.js?v=1#a

Inp: ://example.com/test/something.js?v=1#a
Out: ://example.com/testcontent/something.js?v=1#a

Inp: https://example.com/test/something.js?v=1#a
Out: https://example.com/testcontent/something.js?v=1#a
```

I know I can "fake" an absolute `Uri` by assigning a host so I can access `Segments` property and use `UriBuilder`. The problem is I cannot find a good way to get the output to be in the same format as whatever parts available in the input. The two methods below are my attempt: I can get the segments, modify them and join them back, and build an absolute `Uri`. The problem is, `MakeRelativeUri` changes the form of the output.

```
static readonly Uri BaseUri = new("https://0.0.0.0/index.html/");
static string[] GetUriSegments(Uri uri)
{
    return uri.IsAbsoluteUri ?
        uri.Segments :
        new Uri(BaseUri, uri.OriginalString).Segments;
}

static Uri CreateUri(Uri uri, string[] segments)
{
    var isAbs = uri.IsAbsoluteUri;
    var absUri = isAbs ? uri : new Uri(BaseUri, uri.OriginalString);

    var builder = new UriBuilder(absUri)
    {
        Path = string.Join("", segments)
    };

    var result = builder.Uri;
    if (!isAbs)
    {
        result = BaseUri.MakeRelativeUri(result);
    }

    return result;
}
```

How should I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This covers all the examples provided:

```
Regex rg = new Regex(@"(^|/|//[^/]*/)test/");
var u2 = rg.Replace(u, "$1testcontent/");
```

---

It's unclear if you wish to change only the first `test/` or all, but with this code

```
https://example.com/test/test/something.js?v=1#a
```

becomes

```
https://example.com/testcontent/test/something.js?v=1#a
```

Comment: I try to refrain from using Regex for this (though if there is no solution I would use it as the last resort). There is a minor problem: `https://www.example.com/?url=/test/` would fail (I only want to change the path). Thanks for the idea though, I know how to fix it if I use this solution. As for your question, I need to change all the instances of `test` to `testcontent` as well (my use case is to replace all `_xyz` to `xyz`)